# using emacs auto's to instansiate a stub module (inputs=0, outputs=[]

Tags: emacs, verilog

I am trying to write a top verilog with instansiations of a few identical modules. the first instansiation should be connected outside, while the other instansiations should be floating.
Can anyone help me use the AUTO's with AUTO_TEMPLATE to have emacs connect all inputs to zero, and leave all outputs empty []. 
I don't have any identification in the module IO name indicating if its input or output (so I can't use wildcards) 
Is there a way that the tool can identify all inputs (and connect to zero) and all outputs (and leave floating) by itself?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include an example?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using [verilog-mode](http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode). You might want to use AUTOTIEOFF and/or AUTOUNUSED, see slide 19 [here](http://www.veripool.org/papers/verilog-mode_veritedium_20090925.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I'v managed to have such modules instantiated by using the auto_template with lisp:

/*
    module_name AUTO_TEMPLATE
    (
    .(.*) (@"(if (equal vl-dir \"output\") \"\" (concat vl-width \"'b0\"))"),
    );

*/
that way - all inputs are 0, and outputs are left unconnected!!

Comment: Hi, when I try this, I get:

Invalid use of ‘\’ in replacement text